# SQL Calculate time delay based on sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics, integral

(Note - Example below rewritten from original post to increase readability)

I'm stuck on an SQL problem and could really use some pointers on how to proceed.
(Let me know if this is the wrong place to post it :-) )

I have a table with readings taken every minute showing the flow of water (liters/second) through a sensor. I need to find out how long it takes (approx) for that water to reach a particular point 'downstream'.

The volume (in liters) between the sensor reading and the point of interest is known, but the flowrate varies a alot, so it can't be caculated as a linear function.

My thought is that by summing up all values after a particular reading until the sum is the same as the volume between the 2 points, I can use that to find the time difference. (ie using the integral to calculate)

I've made a first draft that gives my what I need, but it's *extremely* inefficient and doesn't scale to process real-life data at all (500k rows pr year of data).

So I was hoping there would be an analytics functionality that could help me, but ... I'm at a loss.

Does anybody have experience with similar problems in SQL?

Here's a sample setup:

```
--
-- Sample with flow ranging from 1 to 3 liters/minute  
--
create table flow 
(ts             timestamp
,flow_pr_minute numeric);

insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:01:00',1); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:02:00',1);  
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:03:00',2);  
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:04:00',2);  
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:05:00',3);  
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:06:00',2); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:07:00',2); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:08:00',1); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:09:00',3); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:10:00',3); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:11:00',2); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:12:00',3); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:13:00',1); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:14:00',2); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:15:00',3); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:16:00',1); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:17:00',1); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:18:00',3); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:19:00',2); 
insert into flow values ('2020-08-01 00:20:00',3); 

--
-- Sample code
-- when will the water at timestamp 'ts' have reached/passed the 10 liter mark?
--

with SUB as
(
SELECT   ts
         , flow_pr_minute
         ,SUM(flow_pr_minute) OVER(ORDER BY ts) flow_cumul
FROM     flow
)
select  a.ts
        ,a.flow_pr_minute
        ,a.flow_cumul
        ,min(b.ts) as ts_sum_10_liter_or_gt
from SUB a, SUB b
where b.flow_cumul-a.flow_cumul+a.flow_pr_minute >= 10
group by a.ts, a.flow_pr_minute, a.flow_cumul
order by a.ts
/
```

This gives the required output in column 'ts_sum_10_liter_or_gt'
In real life, the amounts and volumes are quite a bit larger - but this shows the essence of the task.

```
ts                  flow_pr_minute  flow_cumul  ts_sum_10liter_or_gt    
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-01 00:01:00 1               1           2020-08-01 00:06:00
2020-08-01 00:02:00 1               2           2020-08-01 00:06:00
2020-08-01 00:03:00 2               4           2020-08-01 00:07:00
2020-08-01 00:04:00 2               6           2020-08-01 00:08:00
2020-08-01 00:05:00 3               9           2020-08-01 00:09:00
2020-08-01 00:06:00 2               11          2020-08-01 00:10:00
2020-08-01 00:07:00 2               13          2020-08-01 00:11:00
2020-08-01 00:08:00 1               14          2020-08-01 00:12:00
2020-08-01 00:09:00 3               17          2020-08-01 00:12:00
2020-08-01 00:10:00 3               20          2020-08-01 00:14:00
2020-08-01 00:11:00 2               22          2020-08-01 00:15:00
2020-08-01 00:12:00 3               25          2020-08-01 00:16:00
2020-08-01 00:13:00 1               26          2020-08-01 00:18:00
2020-08-01 00:14:00 2               28          2020-08-01 00:18:00
2020-08-01 00:15:00 3               31          2020-08-01 00:19:00
2020-08-01 00:16:00 1               32          2020-08-01 00:20:00
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: From your sample data, what is the desired output? Data illustrates better than textual explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, any pairwise matching between datasets or within a dataset will be a challenging computing endeavor especially with very large row count. Without fulling knowing your domain or data to answer *I need to find out how long it takes (approx) for that water to reach a particular point 'downstream'*, your attempted cross join filtered query can possibly be adjusted.

Specifically, consider avoiding exact and reverse duplicates and add time interval against the maximum in data. Possibly, such an interval join can foster use of `ts` as an index assuming it is a defined key/index.

```
with SUB as
(
select   ts
         , flowrate
         , 60*sum(flowrate) over(order by ts) as flow_cumul
         , max(ts) over() as max_ts
from     flow
)
select  a.ts
--      , b.ts
        , round(a.flowrate,1) as flowrate
--      , round(b.flowrate,1) as b_flowrate
--      , round(a.flow_cumul,1) as a_flowcumul
--      , round(b.flow_cumul,1) as b_flowcumul
--      , round(b.flow_cumul-a.flow_cumul,1) as flow_diff
        , b.ts-a.ts as ts_diff
from SUB a
inner join SUB b 
       on b.ts > a.ts and b.ts < a.max_ts
where (b.flow_cumul-a.flow_cumul) > 5E5
  and (b.flow_cumul-a.flow_cumul)-a.flowrate < 5E5;
```

Comment: After reading your comments, I realize I should give a better example and better context -  so I'll rewrite the original post.

(I also realized my original SQL did not give me what I wanted :-( )

The case is from the processing industry, where a chemical is added to water, and a sensor 'downstream' records the impact a particular dose has.
To analyse this properly, the data has to be time-aligned- ie mapping the time an addition was made to the correct impact reading.

With a year of sensor data - it's more that 500k records in total.

Comment: Also - using an inner join as you suggested speeds up the query. Testing on 10 days of sensor data exec time is reduced from 150 seconds to 120 seconds.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as rewriting the SQL to the form suggested (inner join and limiting b.ts range) has a significant boost. But would there be any SQL analytics functionality that could speed this up even more?

Comment: Again, pairwise matching of every possible row is tough computationally in databases even data science (SAS, Matlab, R, Python Pandas/Numpy). SQL's set based paradigm may not be best tool here. Consider importing database data into data science tools that have matrix/array and time series methods. With workhorse CPUs with enough RAM, 500k rows is not too large these days.